# precision of subtracting from a float

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

i just started using SpriteKit and i'm discovering the API. i have an object to move on screen when a button is pressed and held. so what i did is set an NSTimer while the user is still holding and keep calling the same method to move the object every 0.1 seconds. the object does move but while moving at some point it like doesn't show a smooth transition horizontally. so i used NSLog to look at the objects position and i released that it's subtracting 10 points rather than 0.5. here is the code:

```
SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveToX:((CGFloat)[[self childNodeWithName:@"Hero"] frame].origin.x)-0.5 duration:0.1];
[[self childNodeWithName:@"Hero"] runAction:moveLeft];
```

how can i fix that? besides, i realised in the console that the coordinate is like 150.000000 not like 150 or 150.0. could that be the problem?

Another question for the ones who worked with SpriteKit before!!
in a gameplay scene and you want to add a button you add it in the scene class or in the view controller?

Comment: One question per post.

Comment: What happens if you move your - 0.5 inside the parenthesis? Also be sure you have a space after the minus so as not to be using the unary -

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution, i'm using this right now:

```
SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveByX:1 y:0 duration:0];
```

it gives more precise results.

Comment: What you are doing is the equivalent to changing the x position. `hero.position = CGPointMake(hero.position.x + 1, hero.position.y);` is the equivalent with no SKAction needed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are compounding SKAction tweens, setting a new one before the old finishes. It's also possible you are creating timers and not killing them ? Can't be sure without seeing the implementation.

One way to solve the problem is to set a SKAction in the desired direction when the touch begins, and then removing the action when the touch ends. So you will only ever have one SKAction running at a time.

Without seeing your code that creates the NSTimer and how it handles them it's hard to determine exactly what is going on, so I'm basing my answer on what information you have given us. This is one possible scenario.